# Is it okay to save DataTable in session - google charts

Tags: jquery, asp.net, ajax, charts, google-visualization

I have implemented google charts for internal web site and it is a part of dash board page which is on the main Home page. DataTable is created through ajax call (code behind web service method which makes a call to database), query takes 5 seconds to execute and return 12 rows (12 months) and 12 columns.

Everything is working fine but i think it is not a good idea to make a ajax call and get data from the databas everytime user go to the home page within the current session.

I was wondering if it is worth saving data in the session and use it to reload the google charts whenever user hits the home page? Also, Would this slow down the web server when 60 - 70 people will be using this system at the same time?

If you know to achieve the is other better way then please do recommend.

Comment: If you have two horses, add them to race and see what is come first…

Comment: definitely _okay to save DataTable in session_, especially if the query takes 5 seconds for 12 rows, so long as the values won't be changing prior to re-visit to home page...

Comment: i have just tried the session idea and it makes a big difference , as per chrome the Content-Length is 9876 , don't know if its kb or byte. Values can get change prior to re-visit the home page but to get the up to date values either user has to log in again or may be they can have a refresh button to get the up to date values.